# Apache Echarts: autoselect a toolbox feature

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want a brush and a multi-select toolbox feature to be toggled on by default on chart load. There doesn't seem to be an action I can dispatch for it, nor can I find the element in the DOM (because it's rendered to a canvas) so I can't seem to call the onClick on the buttons by grabbing them from the document (unless I can and I don't know how?)

```
let options = {
      toolbox: {
        orient: 'vertical',
      },

      brush: {
        toolbox: ['lineX', 'keep'],
        // Intuition is to have an "default: 'active'/'inactive'" option here
        xAxisIndex: backsplashGridIndex
      },
  }
```

Comment: what have you tried yet, show us some code

Comment: Wish I had something to show. Mostly been digging through the documentation for their Options and Events. Can't find an event to dispatch that would toggle on a toolbox button. The buttons are rendered to a Canvas, not the DOM, so I can't access them from javascript.

One hacky guess is to send a click-event at the canvas coordinates that I expect the buttons to be at... but with inconsistent screen sizes that gets risky real fast.

Answer (score 0):

Found an action to dispatch that works, had to dig through their brush component to figure it out but now that I know it, it's easy to find in their documentation too. I simply dispatch this action in the "on('finished')" (I have leave a flag in the method to make sure it's only called once and not every time an animation finished)

```
echart.dispatchAction({
      type: 'takeGlobalCursor',
      key: 'brush',
      brushOption: {
          brushType: 'lineX',
          brushMode: 'multiple'
      }
});
```